# mdadm raid-1 after restarting usb devices not accessible anymore

Tags: usb, raid-1, mdadm

Is my mdadm software raid in danger of data loss???

My both two new built raid-1 on external usb disks behave strangely.

Both were fine and rebuilt and cat /proc/mdstat showed

```
Every 10,0s: cat /proc/mdstat                                              Mon May  2 20:38:33 2011

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid1 sde1[1] sdc1[2](F)
      1953514432 blocks [2/1] [_U]

md0 : active raid1 sdf2[0] sdd2[2](F)
      452462592 blocks [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>
```

THen i unmounted them and switched off the disks.

Later I switched on each pair at same time and the disk manager in gnome shows "degraded".

Doesnt that work as I suppose it to work.

Do I have to stop the raid before unplugging the disks?

What now?

mdstat is still fine, as posted above, no rebuilding started.

I cant mount the raids, the filesystem shows up as unknown. (should be reiserfs)

```
root@grooverunner:~# dmesg |tail -n 100
[117601.618673] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI disk
[117601.708095] usb 1-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 9
[117601.855616] scsi11 : usb-storage 1-6:1.0
[117602.059429] raid1_end_read_request: 15 callbacks suppressed
[117602.059432] md/raid1:md1: sdc1: rescheduling sector 0
[117602.059562] md/raid1:md1: Disk failure on sdc1, disabling device.
[117602.059566] md/raid1:md1: Operation continuing on 1 devices.
[117602.059600] md/raid1:md1: redirecting sector 0 to other mirror: sde1
[117602.059616] Buffer I/O error on device md1, logical block 0
[117602.059688] md: super_written gets error=-5, uptodate=0
[117602.059703] RAID1 conf printout:
[117602.059708]  --- wd:1 rd:2
[117602.059713]  disk 0, wo:1, o:0, dev:sdc1
[117602.059719]  disk 1, wo:0, o:1, dev:sde1
[117602.064118] Buffer I/O error on device md1, logical block 0
[117602.064196] Buffer I/O error on device md1, logical block 0
[117602.064219] Buffer I/O error on device md1, logical block 0
[117602.064231] Buffer I/O error on device md1, logical block 0
[117602.064245] Buffer I/O error on device md1, logical block 0
[117602.064256] Buffer I/O error on device md1, logical block 0
[117602.064267] Buffer I/O error on device md1, logical block 0
[117602.068056] RAID1 conf printout:
[117602.068064]  --- wd:1 rd:2
[117602.068072]  disk 1, wo:0, o:1, dev:sde1
[117602.865724] scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SAMSUNG  HD204UI               PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[117602.867726] sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[117602.871177] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[117602.877546] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Write Protect is off
[117602.877558] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Mode Sense: 38 00 00 00
[117602.878812] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Incomplete mode parameter data
[117602.878824] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
[117602.889678] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Incomplete mode parameter data
[117602.889689] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
[117602.947154]  sdh: sdh1
[117602.956652] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Incomplete mode parameter data
[117602.956663] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Assuming drive cache: write through
[117602.956671] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdh] Attached SCSI disk
[117605.316083] usb 2-5: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
[117605.467000] usb-storage 2-5:1.0: Quirks match for vid 1e68 pid 001b: 8020
[117605.467062] scsi12 : usb-storage 2-5:1.0
[117606.468921] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Trekstor  DS maxi g.u          PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[117606.473382] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[117606.476584] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[117606.477466] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] Write Protect is off
[117606.477477] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] Mode Sense: 34 00 00 00
[117606.480907] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[117606.490386]  sdi: sdi1 sdi2
[117606.495616] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdi] Attached SCSI disk
[117606.532101] usb 2-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
[117606.684614] usb-storage 2-6:1.0: Quirks match for vid 1e68 pid 001b: 8020
[117606.684664] scsi13 : usb-storage 2-6:1.0
[117606.844129] md/raid1:md0: Disk failure on sdd2, disabling device.
[117606.844130] md/raid1:md0: Operation continuing on 1 devices.
[117606.844153] md: super_written gets error=-5, uptodate=0
[117606.844157] RAID1 conf printout:
[117606.844158]  --- wd:1 rd:2
[117606.844160]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:sdf2
[117606.844161]  disk 1, wo:1, o:0, dev:sdd2
[117606.864053] RAID1 conf printout:
[117606.864058]  --- wd:1 rd:2
[117606.864061]  disk 0, wo:0, o:1, dev:sdf2
[117606.971151] XFS mounting filesystem sdi1
[117607.268814] Ending clean XFS mount for filesystem: sdi1
[117607.684731] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TrekStor  DS maxi g.u          PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[117607.686321] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[117607.691508] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdj] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[117607.692784] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdj] Write Protect is off
[117607.692794] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdj] Mode Sense: 34 00 00 00
[117607.695027] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdj] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[117607.705602]  sdj: sdj1 sdj2
[117607.708803] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdj] Attached SCSI disk
[117607.947471] quiet_error: 441 callbacks suppressed
[117607.947475] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 0
[117607.947502] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 0
[117607.947517] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 0
[117607.947527] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 0
[117607.947537] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 0
[117607.947548] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 0
[117607.947557] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 0
[117607.947566] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 0
[117607.947576] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 0
[117607.947585] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 0
[117608.002977] XFS mounting filesystem sdj1
[117608.417289] Ending clean XFS mount for filesystem: sdj1
[117680.314225] md: super_written gets error=-5, uptodate=0
[117680.315001] md: super_written gets error=-5, uptodate=0
[117731.300492] quiet_error: 139 callbacks suppressed
[117731.300501] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 113115632
[117731.300558] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 113115632
[117731.300606] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 113115646
[117731.300641] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 113115646
[117731.300681] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 0
[117731.300712] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 0
[117731.300751] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 1
[117731.300791] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 113115647
[117731.300830] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 113115647
[117731.300866] Buffer I/O error on device md0, logical block 113115647
[118484.808253] REISERFS warning (device md0): sh-2006 read_super_block: bread failed (dev md0, block 2, size 4096)
[118484.808302] REISERFS warning (device md0): sh-2006 read_super_block: bread failed (dev md0, block 16, size 4096)
[118484.808311] REISERFS warning (device md0): sh-2021 reiserfs_fill_super: can not find reiserfs on md0
```

**EDIT** 
- partially output of parted -l
- the first partition with xfs is non-raid

```
Model: SAMSUNG HD204UI (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdg: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      17.4kB  2000GB  2000GB  reiserfs     dataC  raid


Model: SAMSUNG HD204UI (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdh: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      17.4kB  2000GB  2000GB  reiserfs           raid


Model: Trekstor  DS maxi g.u (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdi: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  537GB   537GB  primary  xfs
 2      537GB   1000GB  463GB  primary  reiserfs     raid


Error: /dev/md0: unrecognised disk label                                  

Error: /dev/md1: unrecognised disk label                                  

Model: TrekStor  DS maxi g.u (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdj: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  537GB   537GB  primary  xfs
 2      537GB   1000GB  463GB  primary  reiserfs     raid
```

Comment: I just see that on one pair I used GPT partition type instead of fd raid autodetection. Is this an additional problem?

Comment: okay i found out I should stop the array before unplugging the disks.

Comment: I cannot relate your "Both were fine and rebuilt" with `[2/1] [_U]` and `[2/1] [U_]`; both indicating that one disk is missing. So they were degraded even before powering off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

luckily after rebooting all went file;  so thanks for reading anyway...

Before I had mdadm.conf configured via

```
mdadm --detail --scan
```

and my fstab looks like this:

```
# dataA2 plus dataB2 = raid md0 463GB auf trekstor 1TB
UUID=07e09d37-975b-fef4-8007-3a9456a04953 none  auto    nouser,noauto   0   0
/dev/md0    /media/AB2  reiserfs    noauto,user 0   0
# dataC plus dataD = raid md1 auf Samsung 2TB
UUID=c7db7ea3-bfd0-4a7e-b87a-039a53567eb2 none  auto    nouser,noauto   0   0
/dev/md1    /media/CD   reiserfs    noauto,user 0   0
# dataA1 plus dataB1 = raid md2 auf trekstor 1TB
UUID=b7dd81d0-2f46-4268-9656-f0747892fcb8 none  auto    nouser,noauto   0   0
/dev/md2    /media/AB1  reiserfs    noauto,user 0   0
```